# Getting "Cannot read property 'bundleId' of null" and "Oget has not been registered" errors in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development

when I run the npm run ios command in my React Native project, I'm encountering the following errors:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bundleId' of null, js engine: hermes
LOG Running "Oget" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}
ERROR Invariant Violation: "Oget" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

How can I resolve these errors?